# Write and Read text in Text File in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, text-files

How to write and read text in text file in windows phone 7?
I try to use Isolated Storage but isolated storage will create a directory and a file that can not be seen by others and that will be done programmatically, but I want to write and read a text file that I created in bin/debug folder...

Answer (score 0):

Using Isolated Storage is a better idea. [This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/07/31/windows-phone-7-how-save-and-read-file-from-isolated-storage.aspx) will help you using Isolated Storage to read and save data to text files in Isolated Storage which is easier and more secure.

Comment: @AlexanderLogger: I would respect if you maintain the use of this site for professional purposes. Thanks.